# oom-killer killing processes despite having plenty of free swap

Tags: linux, memory

This machine has a ton of swap, yet processes still occasionally get killed by the oom-killer. Can anyone explain this behavior, and more importantly how to keep it from occurring?

Dmesg output:

```
python invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x1200d2, order=0, oomkilladj=4
Pid: 13996, comm: python Not tainted 2.6.27-gentoo-r8cluster-e1000 #9

Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff8025ab6b>] oom_kill_process+0x57/0x1dc
 [<ffffffff802460c7>] getnstimeofday+0x53/0xb3
 [<ffffffff8025ae78>] badness+0x16a/0x1a9
 [<ffffffff8025b0a9>] out_of_memory+0x1f2/0x25c
 [<ffffffff8025e181>] __alloc_pages_internal+0x30f/0x3b2
 [<ffffffff8026fea0>] read_swap_cache_async+0x48/0xc0
 [<ffffffff8026ff6f>] swapin_readahead+0x57/0x98
 [<ffffffff80266d0e>] handle_mm_fault+0x408/0x706
 [<ffffffff8057da33>] do_page_fault+0x42c/0x7e7
 [<ffffffff8057baf9>] error_exit+0x0/0x51

Mem-Info:
Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 103
CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  48
CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 136
CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 183
Active:480346 inactive:483 dirty:0 writeback:10 unstable:0
 free:3408 slab:5146 mapped:1408 pagetables:2687 bounce:0
Node 0 DMA free:8024kB min:20kB low:24kB high:28kB active:1156kB inactive:0kB present:8364kB pages_scanned:3246 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2003 2003 2003
Node 0 DMA32 free:5608kB min:5716kB low:7144kB high:8572kB active:1920228kB inactive:1932kB present:2051308kB pages_scanned:2941301 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Node 0 DMA: 8*4kB 3*8kB 4*16kB 3*32kB 4*64kB 3*128kB 2*256kB 3*512kB 3*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 8024kB
Node 0 DMA32: 42*4kB 6*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 2*64kB 1*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 5608kB
325424 total pagecache pages
323900 pages in swap cache
Swap cache stats: add 20776604, delete 20452704, find 7856195/10744535
Free swap  = 151691424kB
Total swap = 156290896kB
524032 pages RAM
9003 pages reserved
331431 pages shared
186210 pages non-shared
Out of memory: kill process 12965 (bash) score 2236480 or a child
Killed process 13996 (python)
```

VM-related sysctls:

```
vm.overcommit_memory = 0
vm.panic_on_oom = 0
vm.oom_kill_allocating_task = 0
vm.oom_dump_tasks = 0
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
vm.page-cluster = 3
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 5
vm.dirty_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.nr_pdflush_threads = 2
vm.swappiness = 60
vm.nr_hugepages = 0
vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 0
vm.hugepages_treat_as_movable = 0
vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0
vm.lowmem_reserve_ratio = 256   256 32
vm.drop_caches = 0
vm.min_free_kbytes = 5740
vm.percpu_pagelist_fraction = 0
vm.max_map_count = 65536
vm.laptop_mode = 0
vm.block_dump = 0
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 100
vm.legacy_va_layout = 0
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 0
vm.min_unmapped_ratio = 1
vm.min_slab_ratio = 5
vm.stat_interval = 1
vm.numa_zonelist_order = default
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this page](http://linux-mm.org/OOM) for some information that may help in diagnosing your problem.

In particular, you need to look at `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/slabinfo` for more information as a start.

Answer (score 2):

You have a device driver or other kernel subsystem allocating a large amount of real-memory.
That's the reason it's not swapping out to your swap space.

You need to identify the work-load you are doing and try to isolate the kernel system
that's allocating large amounts of memory.

Comment: How did you determine this is the problem? And how do I find the subsystem responsible?

Comment: Only in kernel modules can alloc pinned memory. All of your memory allocations causing you grief are in the kernel.  None of the available swap space is being utilized: see Free swap  = 151691424kB vs total swap.  

I would first identify and eliminate as culprits any 3rd party drivers you might have.  
Then look at drivers which move large amounts of data, disk and network.  
What are you doing on your system that is moving large amounts of data?

Comment: The system has a tmpfs mounted for use in /tmp, which is one of the reasons it has a large swap allocated.